# Notepad++ Je suis Charlie edition not allowing Fn button

Tags: notepad++, fn-key

I just updated my [Notepad++ to the “Je suis Charlie” edition](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html) and found out that I can no longer use these key combinations on my [Lenovo Thinkpad L420](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/l-series/l420/):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Play/Pause/Stop/Next/Prev</kbd>

Any suggestions as to how can re-enable this?

Comment: You mean you can't use those keys outside of Notepad++?

Comment: @Vinayak - No. Earlier, while I am working on the Notepad++ window, I could press **fn** + **pause** and the music would pause. Now it doesn't respond when I am on the Notepad++ window

Comment: That's what I'm asking you. Do the key combinations work when you're not using Notepad++?

Comment: @Vinayak - Yes they do. As a matter of fact, they used to work even with Notepad++ before the update. Hence the question

Comment: This is curious indeed. `Fn` keys work perfectly fine on my Lenovo with Je suis Charlie edition of Notepad++. However, my notebook does not have media keys. You could try tweaking BIOS settings to see if you can enable `Fn Key Lock` [as shown here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KIm1V.jpg) and if that helps. If not, you might want to consider reverting back to [version 6.7.3](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.3.html) which is essentially the same as Je suis Charlie edition. See [changelog](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.4-je-suis-charlie-edition.html).

Comment: @Vinayak - Oh finally! It worked ... I absent-mindedly used the key combination while using Notepad++ and it worked! What was the problem? I don't know, but this was definitely after I restarted my PC. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: See the developer comment on Twitter, it may be "God" who disabled this key because FN is an acronym for Front National, a controverted political party in France ;) https://twitter.com/Notepad_plus/status/685442377524330496